# UDP socket server in C not receiving packets

Tags: c, sockets, select, network-programming, udp

I have an UDP client (proxying on behalf of other clients), which does a `sendto()` to my UDP server, which uses `select()` and `FD_ISSET()` to handle all the incoming requests. Both my client and the server are on the same box.

(client)

```
sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );

setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_IP, IP_PKTINFO, &enabled, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_IP, IP_TRANSPARENT, &enabled, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_IP, IP_RECVORIGDSTADDR, &enabled, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enabled, sizeof(int));

/* client_addr points to the source IP (i.e. other client's IP) */
bind(sock_fd, (const struct sockaddr *)client_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

/* dst_addr points to this box's IP */
sendto(sock_fd, dns_packet_buffer, data_len, 0,
            (const struct sockaddr *)dst_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

(server) - excerpt not the full code, obviously!

```
FD_ZERO(&read_set);
FD_SET(fd, &read_set);
select(num_of_fds, &read_set, &write_set, &error_set);
if (FD_ISSET(fd, read_set))
    reply(fd, source_addr.sa.sa_family);
```

In what scenarios can `sendto()` returns success but the `FD_ISSET()` returns false? This seems to be happening for me!

If I don't proxy on behalf of other clients (i.e., other clients directly talk to the server) then it works. Only when I try to proxy there seem some error. What am I doing wrong and where?

Comment: Have you used a network monitor (like e.g. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)) to see that the packet is actually sent from the client and that the server computer receives it? Maybe it's a problem with the proxy? Have you checked its logs?

Comment: adding to @JoachimPileborg  [example-here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/283/simple-usage-of-tcpdump/)

Comment: Many scenarios, but the real question would be: when select can be "waked up" if there are no fd set  to read? BTW how could select be called with 4 params? Select prototype is `int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);`

Comment: What about `num_of_fds`? Is it set to 1?

Comment: `IP_TRANSPARENT` requires root privileges. Are you running the client proxy as root? Is that your real code or does your real code check function call return values (you definitely should be checking)? If you are not running as root and are not checking return values then it is likely that both the `setsockopt` and perhaps also `bind` have failed but nobody was there to see it or hear it.

Comment: the first problem you have is that you aren't even checking if anything is successful. how do you even know the socket was created or bound? also why are you passing sizeof(struct sockaddr)?? you should pass sizeof(client_addr) which we don't event know if its a pointer or not. show us the rest of the code I see tons of reasons this will all fail.

Comment: also forget about wireshark. I can tell the packet is not being sent from the client by the code its completely wrong. I recommend you do "man socket" if you want to test your server you can use netcat "nc -u localhost portno" it will let you send udp packets similar to how telnet works. from what I understand you are attempting to bind the socket to the clients ip address? in what world will that work? people commonly create sockets wrong as well. it make work to do it that way but it should really be "socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)"

Comment: How are you calculating **num_of_fds**? Remember it needs to be at least 1 greater than the highest numbered FD you are testing (see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select))

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: As noted in the question, both the programs are running on the same box. Will tcpdump or wireshark help if the packet is sent within the same host?!

Comment: @AlanAu: Oh I definitely check for the return code. I did not want write the entire code here. Obviously! :) Yes, my client code is running with root privileges for sure. Also no bind failure. In fact, no compile-time or run-time failures whatsoever.

Comment: Yes I think those can intercept traffic in the local interfaces too. But if you're just communicating locally the chances of dropped packages are pretty slim. :) No local firewall which disallows it?